# Angular module config block never accessed

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I am new to angular and I'm trying to load/create an angular module using requirejs.
For some reason the config block never gets called.
I don't think requirejs is to blame here - it's only for the sake of completeness.

```
define(['./IdeaListCtrl'], function (IdeaListCtrl) {

    var moduleName = 'clap.Idea';

    console.log("Loading " + moduleName); // Printed
    angular.module(moduleName, []).config(function () {
        console.log("Config block accessed"); // NOT PRINTED
    });


   console.log("Loaded " + moduleName); // Printed

   return moduleName;

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular essentially lazy-loads its components so you need to bootstrap the module to the page or reference it elsewhere before it will run the config block.